# Collect Pairs from Streams into another Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream, spring-webflux

I have a Java Stream -> `Stream.of(LocalDate1, LocalDate2, LocalDate3....)`

I'm looking to combine this into a stream of objects which each takes 2 consecutive dates,
for example, I would need to create

```
Stream.of(Object1(LocalDate1, LocalDate2),
Object2(LocalDate2, LocalDate3))
```

and so on.

Can anyone help with the same?

Thanks!

I'd be okay with an idea that takes in Reactor Mono/Flux either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with stream you can do it as follows;

```
@Test
void testStream() {

    class DoubleDateObject {
        LocalDate d1;
        LocalDate d2;

        public DoubleDateObject(LocalDate d1, LocalDate d2) {
            this.d1 = d1;
            this.d2 = d2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DoubleDateObject{" +
                    "d1=" + d1 +
                    ", d2=" + d2 +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    LocalDate[] dates = {LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now()};

    List<DoubleDateObject> ret = IntStream.range(0, dates.length)
            .filter(i -> i % 2 == 1)
            .mapToObj(i -> new DoubleDateObject(dates[i - 1], dates[i]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(ret);

}
```

The output will be;

```
[DoubleDateObject{d1=2021-09-03, d2=2021-09-03}, DoubleDateObject{d1=2021-09-03, d2=2021-09-03}]
```

And with flux you can use the following, it will produce the same result;

```
List<DoubleDateObject> ret = Flux.range(0, dates.length)
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 1)
        .map(i -> new DoubleDateObject(dates[i - 1], dates[i]))
        .collectList().block();
```

And if you do not have the array at the first place, then you can do the following which again produces the same output; (replace Arrays.stream(dates) with your stream)

```
final LocalDate[] tmp = {null};
List<DoubleDateObject> ret = Arrays.stream(dates)
            .peek(date -> {
                if (tmp[0] == null) tmp[0] = date;
                else tmp[0] = null;
            })
            .filter(date -> tmp[0] == null)
            .map(date -> new DoubleDateObject(tmp[0], date))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: By the way, in Java 16+, you can replace that nested class with a simple [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395): `record DoubleDateObject ( LocalDate d1 , LocalDate d2 ) {}`. Or use `LocalDateRange` class from *ThreeTen-Extra* library. Also in Java 16+, you can replace `.collect(Collectors.toList())` with `.toList()`.